# Graph API filtering users by specific attribute

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using the C# Graph API SDK

I have a specific attribute that is formatted like this

`extension_{appID}_{attribute}`

I want to return only users who have values with this attribute

I've done this but its not supported. I was wondering if there is another way this could be done.

```
graphServiceClient.Users.Request()
.Filter("extension_{appID}_{attribute} ne null")
.GetAsync();
```

Comment: Try to add ConsistencyLevel header: var options = new List<QueryOption>
                {
                    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
                };
                graphServiceClient.Users.Request(options)
.Filter("extension_{appID}_{attribute} ne null")
.Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
.GetAsync(); Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#user-properties (second table)

Comment: Hey this seem like it worked, put this as the answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `ConsistencyLevel` header (code for SDK v4)

```
var options = new List<QueryOption> 
{ 
    new QueryOption("$count", "true") 
}; 

var result = graphServiceClient.Users
                .Request(options)
                .Filter("extension_{appID}_{attribute} ne null")
                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                .GetAsync();
```

Documentation:

[Advanced queries - user properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#user-properties)